# React Native Tests using Jest crashes on type ErrorHandler in error-guard.js:14

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-navigation

I have a React Native application. When running my tests with Jest, it crashes with the following output:

```
<root-dir>/node_modules/@react-native/polyfills/error-guard.js:14
    type ErrorHandler = (error: mixed, isFatal: boolean) => void;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'ErrorHandler'

      at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/jest/setup.js:402:6)
```

I'm using jest `^29.2.1` and here's my "jest" object in my `package.json` file:

```json
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native)",
    ]
  }
```

Also, here's my `babel.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

Note that my test suite (`__test__` folder) only contains the default app rendering test.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? I've tried several solutions I saw on other posts, including adding `"node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation)"` or `"/node_modules/(?!(@react-native|react-native)/).*/"` to my `"transformIgnorePatterns"` inside my `package.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: i was able to fix this using the following regex:

```
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?react-native|@react-native|@react-navigation)"
]
```

If anyone has any suggestions or a better way to setup this overall, don't hesitate to add it below! Thanks!